# Youtube community

Tags: discussion

The Brewing youtube community seems very strong. Lots of people asking and answering questions on in the comments sections but these get lost with time as you can't search comments for Q&A very easily.

Can we start contacting brew vloggers to make a shout-outs within the youtube community to bring traffic over for Q&As.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea: if you see a good question asked in YouTube comments, search for it here: if it's already been asked and answered, post a link - if it *hasn't* been asked here yet, *ask it!* (Give credit back to the original YouTube author, of course)

If nothing else, this can be a source of useful questions that haven't occurred to anyone here yet; potentially, it could draw in more folks with interest in the topic!

Comment: Yeah that could be an idea for building a library of Q&A and more experienced users can then answer and vote up A's